# Tomcat w/ SSL, Client/Server Auth on portion of site

Tags: tomcat, authentication, ssl, client-server, client-certificates

I'm trying to set up my Apache Tomcat server so that SSL works over the entire site, and client/server auth is enforced on a portion of the site. The customer has given me their root CA (in .crt form) to use for trust. They will use their client certificate to attempt to connect to `https://<site>/sso/login`, and upon authentication, the site should allow them to interact RESTfully with that portion.

First off, I'm using Apache Tomcat 6. I have a site that is set up to use SSL with the following connector in `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="16" 
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           scheme="https" secure="true"clientAuth="want"
           sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\ssl\keystore"
           keystorePass="***" truststoreFile="C:\ssl\keystore"
           truststorePass="***"
           />
```

This should mean that I want SSL on the entire site, but will "want" client certificates. (Client certificates will be needed for the portion of the site that helps open an SSO connection.) And, indeed, SSL works fine. I have a GoDaddy-signed SSL certificate in the keystore.

For the SSO portion with client credential needs, back to `server.xml`, I'm using a memory realm:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

So, that in `tomcat-users.xml`, I can use:

```
<role rolename="sso"/>
<user username="CN=***, OU=***, C=**" password="null" roles="sso"/>
```

... where the username matches the customer's client certificate's DN info. (Does spacing in the username matter?)

And, in `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SSO</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/sso/login</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>sso</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>sso</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Lastly, I've added the customer's root CA to `keystore` using

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" 
  -import 
  -alias customer_root 
  -keystore "C:\ssl\keystore" 
  -trustcacerts 
  -file "C:\ssl\customer_root.crt" 
  -storepass "***"
```

Here is my dilema... When they go to the `https://<site>/sso/login`, the client authentication *is* attempted, but they get a HTTP 401 error. So, I've done something wrong.

To make things harder, the customer cannot give me any more information about the authentication on his side than "HTTP 401".

I've gone through many, many sources to set up and create self-signed CA keys with authorized client keys that I've attempted to use via a java client that I've coded for the purpose that will connect to the site and POST to `~/sso/login`, but each time I re-code/re-package/re-run tests I *also* get a HTTP 401 instead of being able to connect at least once.

So, either I set up Tomcat incorrectly, or I'm not setting up the customer's CA correctly, but I can't figure out which, even by coding my own client. I'm stumped.

Does anything above look incorrect? Am I missing a piece of configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer, for anyone who comes along and needs the information.

In the configuration file tomcat-users.xml...

```
<role rolename="sso"/>
<user username="CN=***, OU=***, C=**" password="null" roles="sso"/>
```

Should NOT have a password of "null" but a password of ""

```
<role rolename="sso"/>
<user username="CN=***, OU=***, C=**" password="" roles="sso"/>
```